# Nifi - Use backslash (\) in a flowfile attribute

Tags: windows-10, apache-nifi

Hi I'm trying to dynamically create a atrribute value with Nifi and it looks something like this

```
$(absolute.path:substringAfterLast('\'):trim)
```

I'm not able to escape that backslash, is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this in different ways.

`Method1:`

Instead of using **`substringAfterLast`** function use **`replaceAll`** function to get the value after

**`\ (last backslash)`**.

Use ***UpdateAttribute*** processor

- add new property as

  ***`val`***

  `${absolute.path:replaceAll('(.*)(?:\\\\(.*?))+$', '$2'):trim()}`

This `regex` will extract the value after last backslash and replaces the `absolute.path` attribute value with the extracted value.

*(or)*

`Method2:`

Use **`substringAfterLast`** + **`trim`** functions

```
${absolute.path:substringAfterLast("\\"):trim()}
```

Comment: I tried that but it's escaping the single quote after the second back slash, is this a bug?

Comment: @Greg, I edited the answer, please try with this approach..!!

Answer (score 1):

This should do: `${absolute.path:substringAfterLast('\\'):trim()}`.
Your problem is, that you used `()` instead of `{}`, you didn't add `()` after the `trim` function and you didn't escape the backslash.

This way works.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Shu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55307396/11402912):

You can also use the `path` attribute of your Flowfile to retrieve it's parent directory. If I had

`C:\foo\bar\myfile.txt` then `${path}` will give you `bar\`

I don't know what you want to do with the substring after the last `\` considering how `@{absolute.path}` gives you `C:\something\like\this\`